# Using automapper to map nested objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I have a Customers EF POCO class which contains a reference to the Address table.

The following code seems to work, but I'm not sure it's the cleanest way to do this.  Is there a better way to map this using only a single Map call?

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details(string ID)
    {
        BusinessLogic.Customers blCustomers = new BusinessLogic.Customers("CSU");
        DataModels.Customer customer = blCustomers.GetCustomer(ID);

        CustomerDetailsViewModel model = new CustomerDetailsViewModel();

        Mapper.CreateMap<DataModels.Customer, CustomerDetailsViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<DataModels.Address, CustomerDetailsViewModel>();
        Mapper.Map(customer, model);
        Mapper.Map(customer.Address, model);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on what your `CustomerDetailsViewModel` looks like. For example, if your `Address` class looks something like this:

```
public class Address 
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

and `CustomerDetailsViewModel` contains properties following this convention:

> When you configure a source/destination type pair in AutoMapper, the
>   configurator attempts to match properties and methods on the source
>   type to properties on the destination type. If for any property on the
>   destination type a property, method, or a method prefixed with "Get"
>   does not exist on the source type, AutoMapper splits the destination
>   member name into individual words (by PascalCase conventions).

*(Source: [Flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening))*

Then, if `CustomerDetailsViewModel` has properties:

```
public string AddressStreet { get; set; }
public string AddressCity { get; set; }
```

Just one mapping from `Customer` to `CustomerDetailsViewModel` will work. For members that don't match that convention, you could use `ForMember`.

You can always use `ForMember` for every single address property as well:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DataModels.Customer, CustomerDetailsViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Street, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Address.Street));
    /* etc, for other address properties */
```

Personally, I wouldn't be too worried about calling `.Map` twice. At least that way it's very clear that both `Address` and `Customer` properties are being mapped.