# How do I use AutoMapper to map Foreign Key Values?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I'm currently using AutoMapper on an MVC Project running Code-First Entity Framework.

Is it possible to Map Foreign Key values within AutoMapper?

For example, I've stripped apart a piece of my Model below:

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public int AccountTypeID { get; set; }

    //Not included in Account Table in Database
    //  -Get "Type" column from dbo.AccountType table
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

On my Account Details page, I would like to display the name of the AccountType on the page rather than the ID. The AccountTypeID is an FK relating to the AccountType table within my database.

My Current mapping for this is fairly straight forward:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Models.Account, DataLayer.Account>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DataLayer.Account, Models.Account>();
```

Is this possible by using a ForMember? Or do I have to make some changes on my model as well to achieve this?

Comment: This shows an example of using *formember* mapping to show a property of a nested object: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337098/using-automapper-to-map-nested-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337098/using-automapper-to-map-nested-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your configuration

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AccountType, string>().ConvertUsing(a => a.Name);
```